# Ajax update panel causes blank space

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I made an updatepanel to update a part of my code which uses a literal text to display html codes. I'm not sure why but when i use the same code on Page_Load, it came out funky.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //Bind Staff Monitor Filter
       filterLiteral.Text = PortalClass.getStaffFilter();

       //Bind Staff Filter Data
       loginPoolLiteral.Text = PortalClass.getLoginPoolData();
}
```

The original intent was for it to look like:

[image: original]

But the postback causes a blank space and my tags, (All, HTC Department etc) to instead of filtering the picture, brings me to the top of the page:

[image: original]

Here is my code for default.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCrowdMonitor" runat="server" 
    RenderMode="Inline">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    //Some html codes
            <asp:Literal ID="filterLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal ID="loginPoolLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Bind Staff Monitor Filter
    filterLiteral.Text = PortalClass.getStaffFilter();

    //Bind Staff Filter Data
    loginPoolLiteral.Text = PortalClass.getLoginPoolData();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to see with Firebug what is the page render after postback?

Comment: i dont know what's that. firefox extension?

Comment: Yes it's an extension. Or just look at the rendered html say by doing ViewSource or in IE8+ press F12 and you will see Developer Tools.

Comment: @Freak_Droid
Hey sorry for the late reply, hope you guys will see this. I checked the rendered html but both came out exactly the same. But i suspect the CSS isnt loaded with the html code. So its just plain html code without it's CSS. Any idea how to fix it?